# Displaying an image in DetailVC keeps throwing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, viewcontroller

I am having difficulty displaying an image in the showDetailVC. I am also getting fatal error regarding  "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value " I am getting the url and the title but image will not display. Any help would be appreciated. My 2 view controllers are below.

```
import UIKit

class ShowDetailVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailProofImage: UIImageView!

    var imageName: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func commonInit(imageName: String, title: String) {
        let imageURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: imageName)
        if let url = imageURL {
            // Problem is here\            
            self.detailProofImage.sd_setImage(with: url as URL)
            self.title = title
        }
    }
}

import UIKit

class ShowPopOverViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ShowPopupview: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let data = GlobalM.showsArray

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        tableView.register(MyShowTableViewCell.nib(),forCellReuseIdentifier: MyShowTableViewCell.identifier)

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count 
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { return 120
        }
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyShowTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyShowTableViewCell

        let value = GlobalM.showsArray[indexPath.row]
        self.title = ("\(value.nameOfShow) Classes")
        let imageURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: value.photoURL)
        if let url = imageURL {

            cell.proofImageView.sd_setImage(with: url as URL)
        }
        cell.showLabel.text = value.nameOfShow
        cell.dateLabel.text = value.dateOfEvent
        cell.groupLabel.text = value.group
        cell.divisionLabel.text = value.division
        cell.classLabel.text = value.event
        cell.entLabel.text = "\(value.entries)"
        cell.posLabel.text = "\(value.position)"
        cell.ptsLabel.text = "\(value.points)"

        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let value = GlobalM.showsArray[indexPath.row]
        let vc = ShowDetailVC()
        vc.commonInit(imageName: value.photoURL, title: value.event)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ShowPopOverViewController: MyShowTableViewCellDelegate {

    func didTapButton(with title: String) {
        print("\(title)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Storyboards? You might be getting a fatal error because you have are initializing the `ShowDetailVC` inside `didSelectRow`. Try removing the `@IBOutlet` and add that imageView to the view of the `ShowDetailVC` as a subview.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried that and still get the same error, only now it shows on the subview line "view.addSubview(detailProofImage!)" I am not sure how to trace where the error is originating from, ie on the DetailVC or the main VC?

Comment: Try replacing the `@IBOutlet` with this: `var detailProofImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)`